# How can I search in Nixpkgs for a package expression?

Tags: nix

From the manual:

> Components are installed from a set of Nix expressions that tell Nix
> how to build those packages, including, if necessary, their
> dependencies. There is a collection of Nix expressions called the
> Nixpkgs package collection that contains packages ranging from basic
> development stuff such as GCC and Glibc, to end-user applications like
> Mozilla Firefox.

Lets assume I want to search for the nix expression of the package Go for example. Where should I look in the [repository](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs) to find the right file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking Nix for metadata about the given package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56118564/asking-nix-for-metadata-about-the-given-package) -- note that the OP there is explicitly asking where the source comes from, so the answers to that question are a superset of what you're asking for here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't think this is a duplicate, because the linked question is not as specific. It wouldn't show up for a search query like this question.

Comment: @RobertHensing, forming links that wouldn't show up in the search is the entire point of and benefit to having the close-as-duplicate mechanism -- so we can direct folks whose search terms find an answer like this to the existing, pre-answered instance. That's part of why, unlike other close methods, closing a question as a duplicate doesn't auto-delete it and lets it still be upvoted while closed -- because _good duplicates_ (which is to say, ones that use different terminology) _add value_.

Comment: Fair enough then

Comment: Wait, no, this would make it impossible to answer this question, which _is_ different.
It should be marked as similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My tool of choice is `nix repl`. Often its tab completion is sufficient to find attribute names. Sometimes you might want to use https://search.nixos.org/packages.

For a convenient workflow, you could set `EDITOR` and use the `:edit` command in `nix repl`. Usually I open nixpkgs in VSCode and then run `nix repl .` in a VSCode terminal so I can Ctrl+click file locations as well.

I never use the directory structure, because search is so much more convenient.

```
[~/nixpkgs]$ export EDITOR=...  # nano doesn't seem to work for this
[~/nixpkgs]$ nix repl .

nix-repl> :edit go
```

or

```
nix-repl> go.meta.position
"~/nixpkgs/pkgs/development/compilers/go/1.17.nix:278"
```

This generally gives you the location of a `mkDerivation` call, or a call to a similar function.

To get the location where an attribute is defined, use

```
nix-repl> builtins.unsafeGetAttrPos "go" pkgs
{ column = 3; file = "~/nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix"; line = 12753; }
```

And then there's the recursive directory search option (like `grep -R`, IDE-integrated search, etc). This generally works really well as package names tend to be specific. Too bad `go` isn't. We generally don't do crazy code formatting in Nix, a leading space and an equals sign do a pretty good job at finding definitions, even for `go`, if you ignore the ones in `lib/`.

```
[~/nixpkgs]$ git grep -n ' go ='
lib/attrsets.nix:125:    go = prefixLength: hasValue: value: updates:
lib/debug.nix:234:      go = x: generators.toPretty
lib/deprecated.nix:92:    let go = xs: acc:
lib/filesystem.nix:29:    let go = path:
lib/generators.nix:237:    go = indent: v: with builtins;
lib/trivial.nix:500:      go = i:
nixos/modules/security/apparmor/includes.nix:9:    let go = { path ? null, mode ? "r", trail ? "" }:
pkgs/stdenv/booter.nix:63:      go = pred: n:
pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix:12753:  go = go_1_17;
pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix:21043:    go = buildPackages.go_1_16;
pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix:21046:    go = buildPackages.go_1_17;
pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix:21049:    go = buildPackages.go_1_18;
pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix:21055:    go = buildPackages.go_1_16;
pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix:21058:    go = buildPackages.go_1_17;
pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix:21061:    go = buildPackages.go_1_18;
pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix:26493:    go = go_1_16;
```